# Can media such as photos, music, etc be encrypted?

Tags: android, encryption, media, photo

I am looking for a method to encrypt media which can only be read while a person has an "active" account eg. the media cannot be stolen... it would seem like that does not make sense if the application displaying the media can decrypt the media and display the actual photo.

Is the encryption slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve such functionality by using two-way encryption/decryption, based on **password phrase** (in binary format) and any two-way encryption algorythm, like XOR for example.

XOR encryption/decryption has linear complexity, it's extremely fast and it is hard to crack the encrypted data if you don't know what encryption algorythm has been used in first place.

The actual XOR password phrase can be associated with the user's account. As long as the account is active, the password phrase can be accessed and therefore the encrypted media can be decrypted. If the user is offline (logged out), the password phrase is inaccessible and therefore the encrypted media stays encrypted.

This can be implemented as a service - the user downloads music which can be played only while the user is logged in (i.e. has the means to access the password phrase to decrypt the music and play it).

*If the key is random and is at least as long as the message, the XOR cipher is much more secure than when there is key repetition within a message.[3] When the keystream is generated by a pseudo-random number generator, the result is a stream cipher. With a key that is truly random, the result is a one-time pad, which is unbreakable even in theory.*

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher

Comment: Thank you this is exactly the application I am looking for but I have to put it all together, the mobile application, server, opencart/payment processing, thank you

Comment: XOR alone doesn't get you far. The PRNG must be good for it to be secure. Using the fast mersenne-twister is not a good idea in this case. Instead a better encryption would be to use AES in CBC/CTR/GCM/... mode (not ECB!).

Answer (score 1):

Any crypto algorithm can be used. It should not be slower than to encrypt any file of the same size.

Comment: directly changing values like a = alkdfjals;kfj;laksj is not that secure right? I guess I'll have to look into this, you have to take the bits and scramble them... ehhh